# Apache2 + Php + Pthreads HowTos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. What I would really love to do is `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` but compile PHP with `--enable-maintainer-zts` so I could later install pthreads with `pecl install pthreads`. Sadly, I understand that it is not possible. I know that the easiest way is to recompile PHP together with apache support and zts. However I really like the way the standard Ubuntu PHP package is configured and I am used to the paths for CLI php.ini config, Apache php.ini config and other paths for modules and files that this Ubuntu package defines. So I just want to change the package source a little bit and install it.

```
# Get the stuff necessary to build the package
sudo apt-get build-dep php5-common

# Get the package source
sudo apt-get source php5-common
```

At this point I am getting sources not for the php5-common package but the whole php5 package. If I would `sudo make && make install` at this point, would it mean that I am installing a lot of unnecessary stuff?

```
# Add configuration options
./configure --enable-maintainer-zts
```

Does this mean that I am appending a configuration option? Or am I generating a whole new config?

**Alternative at this point** Is there a way of getting the config options that this package defines, so that I can grab a php source from php.net and compile it with

```
$ ./configure  --prefix=package_prefix \ // Option 1 from package
--enable-embed \ // Option 2 from package
--with-regex=php \ // Option 3 from package
```

*Continuing the main idea ...*

*Solution 1*

```
# Compile (Not compiling)
sudo make && make install
```

Will I be building PHP with EVERYTHING at this point? If I compile like this, I will not be able to remove the mess I made using `sudo apt-get purge php5`?

*Solution 2*

```
# ReCompile the package
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

This does not compile also.
Please correct my steps, so I can install everything correctly.